# How to mount partitions as normal user?

Tags: partitioning, mount, encryption

I have made several partitions on my hard disk. One is encrypted (LUKS) and contains my sensitive data. I don't want this partition to be mounted permanently (by automounting it via fstab), only when I (or another user) need(s) it.

Problem: I can only mount these as an admin. No normal user can mount partitions on my system. A least, I don't know any other way to do this. I'm running a dual boot system (win7, Ubuntu 14.04) on a Dell Inspiron N5050.

Question: how can I let normal users mount partitions in general, and an encrypted partition in particular?

`pmount` is not the solution here; it only mounts external devices.

Comment: I don't know if you can understand it but a solution for a similar problem in terms of programming to access a private variable will be to create a public method that can access the variable. On Ubuntu, a similar approach will be to create a link to the file on that partition on a location which the other user can access. I'm still not sure if that would work for other users. Try it and I will post it as an answer if it works.

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea what you're talking about, but I'm sure it's a good solution:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your `/etc/sudoers` with

```
sudo visudo
```

**Don't** use `nano`, `vi` or something else and add the lines below

```
%users ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/mount
%users ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/umount
```

You still need `sudo` to mount and unmount your devices, but no password.

Comment: You can edit in (e.g.) `gedit` with `sudo EDITOR=gedit visudo` ;)

Comment: I'm probably doing something wrong here. These are the steps I have taken: 1) add the exact lines (including % marks) to /etc/sudoers, 2) logged in with a normal user account. Helas, it didn't work. Just to be clear on this: I have added '%users ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/mount' and 
'%users ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/umount' to the bottom of the file.

Comment: The error message is?

Comment: well, it's in Dutch, but the translation is something like this: 'authentication is required to mount (for example) /dev/sda1'.

Comment: Sorry, added an explanation to my answer.

Comment: Thx! One more question: is there a way to get this to work in a file browser, in my case Nautilus?

Comment: @A.B.: good one! reminded me that I need to put `umount` in mine!  **;-)**

Comment: Sorry, be fair, that's a completely different question. It's possible with some changes in your `fstab`, but please ask a new question and accept this one with a click on the check mark at the left side of the answer. **;)**

Comment: My apologies for that, you have certainly answered my question, I have just marked it as answered, many thanks for that. The thing is that - since I am a relatively new on Linux in general - I am not always sure what to ask. Again apologies and thanks, you have answered my question.