# How to mount partitions as normal (non-root) uesr?

Tags: dual-boot, permissions, mount

I have a dual-boot setup with several NTFS partitions shared between Ubuntu and Windows. I want those partitions to be auto-mounted at startup. But I want them to be mounted as normal user, because mounting as root sometimes causes problems like [this](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14376) for me. I tried mounting with `fstab` but it mounts those partitions as root. And the utility `pmount` seems to only works for removable drives.

Is there any utility or script that I can use to mount those partitions as a normal user (like file managers do) at system startup?

Comment: Not a duplicate of- "https://askubuntu.com/questions/703876/how-to-mount-partitions-as-normal-user"  as I think the solution there still mounts partitions as root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read `man mount.ntfs`, it will tell you how to mount your partitions as a user (with the `uid=` and `gid` parameters. From the `man mount.ntfs` page:

```
Access Handling and Security
   By default, files and directories are owned by the effective user and group of the mounting process, and  everybody  has
   full  read,  write,  execution  and directory browsing permissions.  You can also assign permissions to a single user by
   using the uid and/or the gid options together with the umask, or fmask and dmask options.

   Doing so, Windows users have full access to the files created by ntfs-3g.

   But, by setting the permissions option, you can benefit from the full ownership and permissions features as  defined  by
   POSIX. Moreover, by defining a Windows-to-Linux user mapping, the ownerships and permissions are even applied to Windows
   users and conversely.

   If ntfs-3g is set setuid-root then non-root users will be also able to mount volumes.
```

However, `root` is still involved (because "mount"ing is a system-level thing), and unmountable NTFS drives will cause it to hang they're automounted, so don't use `auto` in your `/etc/fstab` entry.

Read `man mount`, especially about the `user` parameter:

```
   The non-superuser mounts.
          Normally, only the superuser can mount filesystems.  However, when fstab contains the user option on a line, any‐
          body can mount the corresponding filesystem.
```

Comment: The problem with fstab mounting for me was that files and folders by default was being owned by root (which doesn't happen when you mount a partition through file manager). After hour-long search about your mentioned "uid" and "umask" parameter I was able to mount the partition so the files and folders becomes owned by user (me) at mount. It solved the problem I was facing. Thanks.